# Is it bad practice to render different content based on user agent?

Tags: seo, single-page-application

I have a Single Page Application with some dynamic content but the Meta tags and stuff don't work when sharing on social sites (for obvious reasons). I was thinking of detecting the user-agent on the server side and rendering a static version of the page when I detect Googlebot or Facebook or others.

Is this good practice? Would it land me in any trouble with any of the social sites/search engines?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

I think you may get a ban from Google for this.

I mean, it is not a good idea at all, cause Google will count it as black SEO.

Google wants to see the same that normal user sees.